# Modal resizable issue

Tags: jquery

iam  using below code to make the modal popup window resizable, but what is happening is the modal-body is not getting resized instead whole window is getting resized. when i resize the popup window the vertical scrollbar in the window should go off but what is happening is the vertical resize is happening after modal-footer. Any suggestions to make it work.

```
$element.find(".modal").resizable({minwidth:300, minHeight:330})
```

In order to check the behavior please refere this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p7o2mkg4/ . when resized vertically blank space appears after footer instead increasing the body space.

Answer (score 0):

$(this).find(".modal-body").resizable({minwidth:300, minHeight:330});

use this it will works

Comment: this is not working as we resize body content is coming out of the window, also the vertical scrollbars are not going off

Comment: the textfields are coming out of the window when resized horizontally

Comment: .modal-body {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 400px;
    padding: 150px;
}                                                                                                       $('.modal-content').resizable({
    //alsoResize: ".modal-dialog",
    //minHeight: 150
});


$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
        'max-height':'100%'
    });
}); hope it will  help

Comment: or u can refer this link https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/PaoDr you will know